# Javascript Change timestap format

Tags: javascript, jquery, timestamp

I initialize my timestamp variable like

```
   var current_time = new Date();
```

My output is in 
Tue Oct 11 2016 15:09:04 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
format. How can I change it to 2016-10-11 07:19:48pm  format?

Comment: Maybe this previous question "How to format a JavaScript date" could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can acheive this using moment.js lib,

just run

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:SS A'); // print 2016-10-11 03:20:88 PM
```